# Ray tracing with Metal only has red channel

Tags: xcode, macos, metal

I was running [Apple's sample code on using Metal to trace rays](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/metal_for_accelerating_ray_tracing) unchanged, as well as a Swift adaption from [Marius Horga's blog](http://metalkit.org/2018/07/14/raytracing-with-metal.html). But the project does not run correctly on my Mac (target for iOS works perfectly fine). After launch, as new passes are finished, only the red channel seems to be accumulated.

Originally, I thought this might be a driver issue, but after updating the OS, new native driver does not seem to work either. I also thought of some hardware defect on my GPU. However, other Xcode projects, playgrounds and apps that utilize Metal renders perfectly fine. I didn't change a bit before I run the sample code *Metal for Accelerating Ray Tracing* on my Mac. I don't know what exactly the problem might be.

[image: With passes increasing, only red channel seem to be accounted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Nvidia GPU and you're running Mojave, you may be out of luck until Nvidia puts together a driver. There's no word from Nvidia as to whether or when that will be.

Both those projects work fine on my 2015 iMac with an AMD GPU, but I get the red render on my 2015 MacBook Pro which has an Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Yes, that is the configuration of my Mac. I tried to run on iGPU, but ended up with IOAF error... I guess I’ll just switch to other Macs. By the way, do other Metal applications work fine on your Nvidia enabled Mac?

Comment: Link to a summary of the Nvidia thread: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042520/drivers/-when-will-the-nvidia-web-drivers-be-released-for-macos-mojave-10-14-/post/5322351/#5322351

Comment: Mostly. I haven't seen a red render until now

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Yeah, having no idea what is magical about this project... I wonder when they release the sample code at WWDC 2018, did any developer participants actually download and run the code on their *old* MacBook Pros with Nvidia GPU and ask Apple engineers about the red thing...